# Data not showing form DataBinding in a Windows Store app

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, windows-store-apps, datacontext

I am developing a Windows Store app. I am setting DataContext of a gridview. Some data are showing others are not showing. Though I can see the data in deserialized class.

Here is my code where I download JSON:

```
private async void loadData(string Id, Order data)
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    http.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
    string partial_url = "rest/admin/order/info.json?id=" + Id;
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await         http.GetAsync(partial_url);
    SingleOrder orderData = new SingleOrder();
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        string jsonMessage;
        using (Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            jsonMessage = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
            orderData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleOrder>(jsonMessage);
            OrderDetailsView.DataContext = orderData.order;                   
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog message = new MessageDialog("Internal server error occured!", "Error!");
        UICommand okCommand = new UICommand("Okay");
        message.Commands.Add(okCommand);
        await message.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

I can see the data here:

[image]

My xaml is:

```
    <GridView x:Name="OrderDetailsView"  Grid.Row="1"  Height="auto" Width="auto" Background="#F0F5F5" SelectionMode="None">

        <Grid Height="500" Width="500" Background="White" Margin="15,15,15,15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                           
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Order Information" Foreground="#31AAE0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Order Id" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Name" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding customerName}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="3" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Order Total" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding grandTotal}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="4" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Order Date" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding created}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="5" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Order Status" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding orderStatus}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="6" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="IP" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ipAddress}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Height="500" Width="500"  Background="White" Margin="15,15,15,15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Shipping Details" Foreground="#31AAE0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                           
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding shipping.id}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>                        
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                            
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding shipping.addressLine1}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>                        
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="3" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                            
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding shipping.addressLine2}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>                        
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="4" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                           
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding shipping.country.name}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>                        
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="5" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                            
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding shipping.email}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>                        
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="6" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Shipping Cost" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding shippingCost}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="7" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Shipping Status" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding shippingStatus}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Height="500" Width="500" Background="White" Margin="15,15,15,15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>                       
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Billing Details" Foreground="#31AAE0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding billing.id}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Address line 1" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="3" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Address line 2" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="4" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Country" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="5" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Email here" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="6" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Payment Status" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding paymentStatus}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>                    
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Grid Height="500" Width="500" Background="White" Margin="15,15,15,15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#F8FAFA">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Order Details" Foreground="#7E7E81" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding items}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContactGroups}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFFFFF" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionMode="None">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Border BorderBrush="#666666" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.2"  Grid.Column="0">
                                                    <TextBlock Name="tb1" Text="{Binding productName}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="25,0,25,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="#636D6F" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                </Border>
                                                <Border BorderBrush="#666666" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.2" Grid.Column="1" >
                                                    <TextBlock Name="tb2" Text="{Binding price}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="#636D6F" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                                </Border>                                                    
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>

                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <Rectangle StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
                            </ListView>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Sub Total" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding subTotal}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Total Tax" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding totalTax}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Shipping Cost" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding shippingCost}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Shipping Tax" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding shippingTax}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="4">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Handling Cost" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding handlingCost}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Discount" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding totalDiscount}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="6">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Grand Total" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding grandTotal}" Foreground="#666666" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Height="500" Width="500" Background="White"  Margin="15,15,15,15" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#F8FAFA">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Custom Field Details" Foreground="#7E7E81" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <ListView x:Name="CustomFieldDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContactGroups}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFFFFF" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionMode="None">

                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="25,0,25,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="20" Foreground="#636D6F" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="20" Foreground="#636D6F" Grid.Column="1"/>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        </ListView>

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>       

    </GridView>
```

My output is:
[image]

In shipping an billing only id is showing other fields like address_line1 address_line2 there are not showing.

Here is singleOrder class:

```
public class SingleOrder
{
    public Order order { get; set; }
}
```

I can see that all the data are properly deserialized and I can view the in debugger. But when I put them in textblock nothing shows.

Comment: Can you provide source for `SingleOrder`.

Comment: I asked for a code to verify it your values are stored in properties - as you are using naming conventions for fields which does not matter - what matters is for binding to work you must use properties, are you?.

Comment: @Rafal > Sorry I didn't understand. Can you please explain some more? I am new to windows store app development.

Comment: For binding to work you need to expose your values as properties eg `public Order order { get; set; }` in contrast to exposing fields `public Order order;`. The `{ get; set; }` part is a compiler trick that will generate a field and two methods to access that filed (GET the value and SET the value). This will be enough if you are only displaying the values if you wish to edit then you need the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented.

Comment: @Rafal > I am not editing anything. And everything is set as a property. But still some values are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my `GridView`. Though I was setting dataContext from code but I didn't added `GridView` `itemsSource`.

Just adding this solved the problem:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```